# Pandas - Behaviour/Issue of reindex vs loc for setting values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've been trying to use `reindex` instead of `loc` in pandas as from 0.24 there is a warning about reindexing with lists.

The issue I have is that I use `loc` to change the values of my dataframes.
Now if use reindex i lose this and if I try to be smart I even get a bug.

Contemplate the following case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.np.zeros(4, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
ds = pd.Series(data=[1]*3)
```

I want to change a subset of values (while retaining the others), so `df` keeps the same shape.

So this is the original behaviour which works (and changes the values in a subset of df['a'] to 1)

```
df.loc[range(3), 'a'] = ds
```

But when I'm using the reindex I fail to change anything:

```
df.reindex(range(3)).loc['a'] = ds
```

Now when I try something like this:

```
df.loc[:, 'a'].reindex(range(3)) = ds
```

I get a `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call` error message.

For reference I am using pandas 0.24 and python 3.6.8

Comment: `reindex` returns a copy. Modifying the copy does not change the original. That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer from @coldspeed was the easiest, though the behaviour of the warning is misleading.
So `reindex` returns a copy when `loc` doesn't.
From the pandas docs:

> A new object is produced unless the new index is equivalent to the current one and copy=False.

So saying `reindex` is an alternative to `loc` as per the warning is actually misleading.

Hope this helps people who face the same situation.